# CakePHP: Time helper to show age

Tags: datetime, cakephp, helper

I have a MySQL DATETIME field that holds the date of birth of a user. I want to use that date to display the age the user in years.

Is there a method of the Time core helper to do this?

Also, why when you add a DATETIME field to a form in Cake does it not let you select a date less than 1990?

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding new answer because the code will be shown better. How I would do that:

in your model create [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields) like this.

```
var $virtualFields = array(
   'age' => "YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(YourModelName.datetimeField)"
);
```

Then use it as normal field in the model. :)

Comment: this looks good but im gettin a sql error. here is my code var $virtualFields = array(
    'age' => "(YEAR(NOW()-YEAR(User.dob))"
 ); and the error is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS  `User__age` FROM `users` AS `User`   WHERE 1 = 1

Comment: There was a typo - wrong brackets count :) Get the code and try again

Comment: That only works if it is currently after the person's birthday in that year. If the user's birthday is in August, and you run that in March, it will say the user is a year older.

Comment: tyjkenn is correct, and seemingly no solution has still been posted even as long as a year later because this solution was chosen as best despite the obvious flaw. about to post another question shortly...

Answer (score 4):

the function is called timeAgoInWords

```
<?php echo $this->Time->timeAgoInWords(
      '1975-12-29 13:40', 
      array(
            'end'=>'+150 years'
      )
);?>
```

The end parameter mean to display the time ago with words until the date is less than 150 years (at least I haven't heard of 150yo man :)))).

The current result is: born: before 34 years, 9 months, 4 weeks

But also check API and CookBook as Jason suggest

Comment: +1 I didn't know about this function, but I stand by my answer that you should become familiar with PHP date functions!

Comment: thanks for this, now I jsut need to figure out how to show it in years only as in Age: 34

Answer (score 3):

`timeAgoinWords()` may do what you want for the first part. Check out the [Book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1471/Formatting)

This has to do with the automagic form fields. You can adjust the year range with options. Check out the [Book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1408/options-minYear-options-maxYear).

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the calculation using standard PHP functions - look in the date section. I'm not going to tell you how to do it because you'll learn a huge amount by doing it yourself.

I will say that you need to be careful to get an accurate result. 365 days is not always a year and a month has a variable number of days.

You can configure the date selection range in the Cake form helper.

Answer (score 0):

i always use this tested method:

```
/*
 * @return int age (0 if both timestamps are equal or empty, -1 on invalid dates)
 * 2009-03-12 ms
 */
function age($start = null, $end = null, $accuracy = 0) {
    $age = 0;
    if (empty($start) && empty($end) || $start == $end) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (empty($start)) {
        list($yearS, $monthS, $dayS) = explode('-', date(FORMAT_DB_DATE));
    } else {
        $startDate = $this->fromString($start);
        $yearS = date('Y', $startDate);
        $monthS = date('m', $startDate);
        $dayS = date('d', $startDate);
        if (!checkdate($monthS, $dayS, $yearS)) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    if (empty($end)) {
        list($yearE, $monthE, $dayE) = explode('-', date(FORMAT_DB_DATE));
    } else {
        $endDate = $this->fromString($end);
        $yearE = date('Y', $endDate);
        $monthE = date('m', $endDate);
        $dayE = date('d', $endDate);
        if (!checkdate($monthE, $dayE, $yearE)) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    $n_tag = $dayE;
    $n_monat = $monthE;
    $n_jahr = $yearE;
    $g_tag = $dayS;
    $g_monat = $monthS;
    $g_jahr = $yearS;
    $g_date = mktime(0,0,0,$g_tag,$g_monat,$g_jahr);

    if (($n_monat>$g_monat)||(($n_monat == $g_monat)&&($n_tag>$g_tag))||(($n_monat == $g_monat)&&($n_tag==$g_tag))) {
        $age = $n_jahr-$g_jahr; // is correct if one already had his birthday this year
    } else {
        $age = $n_jahr-$g_jahr-1; // is correct if one didnt have his birthday yet in this year
    }
    return $age;
}
```

it can probably be refactured
but it works with leap years and all kinds of stuff. so i never bothered...

it uses a constant you dont have

its just:  define('FORMAT_DB_DATE', 'Y-m-d');